# Linux NetBIOS name relay

Tags: wifi, linux-networking, netbios

I have a bridge, over WiFi, that is using `parprouted` to fudge ARP so that routing works. Is there anything like `dhcrelay` (which relays DHCP requests) but for NetBIOS (Windows File and Print Sharing) names?

The WiFi gateway in question is a cheap Belkin so any other options seem unlikely to work.

**UPDATE**: I will use `nmbd` from samba as a WINS server. DHCP should allow me to configure WINS automatically on the client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WINS and/or the later versions of DNS (which allow auto-registration - Bind 9 and up). Note: neither are NetBIOS, but replacement technologies for spanning/extending Windows resolutions across networks.

Comment: How do I set them up?

Comment: Well, since you mentioned Linux - Samba... It has provisions to run as a WINS server. The Windows clients can then enter its IP as the WINS server within their TCP/IP configurations.

Answer (score 1):

WINS alone will not be enough if you do not configure your clients to actually use the WINS server. There is a thing called [*WINS proxy*](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc959252.aspx) which will forward NetBIOS broadcast name queries to a WINS server and re-broadcast its replies. Samba's [nmbd](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/nmbd.8.html) implements it as well.

A poor man's solution is an [IP helper configuration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UDP_Helper_Address) which has been implemented with some older routers - I think using an iptables DNAT for broadcast addresses should be able to mimic this functionality and work in a similar way.